# How can I wait for this lasso selection window that powerpoint spawns to disappear?

Tags: windows, user-interface, powerpoint, pywinauto, windows-11

I'm trying to wait for this whole screen lasso selection tool to disappear.

I'm using this pywinauto code to reach it, basically start `powerpoint.exe` and send keys to get to that command. If I check for any controls to be visible, it won't work because Powerpoint keeps all it's controls visible.

```
#import pywinauto Application class
from pywinauto.application import Application
#support for env. variables
import os

#set path and arguments for powerpoint
ppt_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE"
ppt_args = r"/b"
ppt_startInfo = f"{ppt_path} {ppt_args}"

#set location to save file
userprofile_path = os.environ.get("userprofile")
rec_file_path = f"{userprofile_path}\Documents"

#start a new process
app = Application().start(ppt_startInfo,timeout=10)

# Access the PowerPoint window
dlg_spec = app.window(title='מצגת1 - PowerPoint')
dlg_spec.wait('enabled')
dlg_spec.type_keys('%')
dlg_spec.type_keys('פ')
dlg_spec.type_keys('זסק')
```

[Ribbon -> Insert -> Screen Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EKaJ.png)

I tried searching for a solution in the documentation of Powerpoint vba and used swapy and au3_spy without much success in finding that control name etc.

Comment: Please use `Application(backend="uia")` and this guide: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html If this is not enough, please reply with a comment here. Please be aware that "uia" backend provides another hierarchy which is more detailed, and also a dialog window may be a child of main window, while in "win32" backend it is always a top level window.

Comment: thanks, I tried this a in the dump_tree() method I don't see anything changed after i'm done capturing a screen recording,
but I think i'm on to something, i wasn't using the 32 bit python and i was using jupyter, when i run with python in terminal i get much more controls shown.

Comment: `"win32"` doesn't mean 32-bit Python, it means Win32 API as a technology under the hood. It is old and doesn't show many controls for modern apps like WPF. Also `sys.platform` is always equal to `"win32"` in any Python on Windows, even if both Windows and Python are 64-bit. That's a common Python thing on Windows.